# using MailChimp API without cURL

Tags: php, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm trying to use the MailChimp API to add subscribers to a list once they've checked a box on a form. I can do this with cURL, and it works fine, but the server that this will be on does not have it enabled. I'm trying to use file_get_contents(), but that gives me a 401 error. I've checked the API key and the list id, and they're both correct. I'm guessing that my syntax is messed up or that I've put something in the wrong place, but I'm not seeing the problem. What I've tried is below. Anyone have any ideas?

```
if (isset($_POST['mailtest']) == 'value1'){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $fname =  $_POST['firstname'];
    $lname =  $_POST['lastname'];
    $mailchimp_api_key = 'apikey';
    $mailchimp_list_id = 'listid';
    $data = array(
              'apikey' => $mailchimp_api_key, 
              'id' => $mailchimp_list_id, 
              'email' => $email
              'status'=>'subscribed'
);
    $memberId = md5(strtolower($email));
    $dataCenter = substr($mailchimp_api_key ,strpos($mailchimp_api_key, '-')+1);
    $endpoint = 'https://' . $dataCenter . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $mailchimp_list_id . '/members/' . $memberId;
    if ($fname && $lname) $data['merge_vars '] = array('FNAME' => $fname, 'LNAME' => $lname);
    $json_data = json_encode($data);
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => "Content-type: application/json",
            "Connection: close\r\n" .
            "Content-length: " . strlen($json_data) . "\r\n",
            'data' => $json_data,
                     ),);
    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($endpoint, false, $context); 
    }
```

Comment: http 401 error means unauthorized. So you aren't correctly authenticating.

Comment: If you want to stick with `file_get_contents()` you need some context to authenticate (read the manual). Take a look at [stream_context_create()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) to create the header you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the Basic authentication header. As well it seems you're including your dataCentre in with your api key, so the below code might need some tweaking since I don't actually know what `$mailchimp_api_key` is set to.

```
// this is improper usage of isset. isset returns a boolean
// since you're not doing a strict match it'll always work, 
// unless mailtest is null or isn't set.
if (isset($_POST['mailtest']) == 'value1') {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $fname =  $_POST['firstname'];
    $lname =  $_POST['lastname'];
    $mailchimp_api_key = 'apikey';
    $mailchimp_list_id = 'listid';
    $data = array(
              'apikey' => $mailchimp_api_key, 
              'id' => $mailchimp_list_id, 
              'email' => $email
              'status'=>'subscribed'
    );
    $memberId = md5(strtolower($email));
    $dataCenter = substr($mailchimp_api_key ,strpos($mailchimp_api_key, '-')+1);
    $endpoint = 'https://' . $dataCenter . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $mailchimp_list_id . '/members/' . $memberId;
    if ($fname && $lname) {
        $data['merge_vars '] = array('FNAME' => $fname, 'LNAME' => $lname);
    }
    $json_data = json_encode($data);
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' =>  implode(
                "\r\n",
                [
                    "Content-type: application/json",
                    "Content-length: " . strlen($json_data),
                    "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("anystring:$mailchimp_api_key") // see note above
                ]
            ),
            'content' => $json_data,
         )
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($endpoint, false, $context); 
}
```

Comment: $mailchimp_api_key is set to the alphanumeric key followed by the -usX number. This code doesn't give a 401 error, so I guess its authenticating, but it's giving a 404 error. The URL generated is the same as the one generated when it used cURL so I'm not sure what it's looking for and not finding.

Comment: It did need some minor tweaking, but it worked after I changed the POST to PUT and changed 'email' to 'email_address'.